# how to display value of multiple toggled checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to count the number of toggle toggled and display it in text and also get the multiple value of the input toggled in an array. I don't know how to use javascript well. So I need help on what to do. I tried using the checkbox javascript to display value it display if its default checkbox but once data-toggle is on toggle it doesn't work.

```
 <table id="godwin" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
     <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg float-right " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#task">Reassign Selected Tasks</button>
     <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg float-right "><span class="circle" id="checkall">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</span> Item Selected</button><br>
      <thead>
       <tr>
        <th><i class="fa fa-question-circle fa2">&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" onclick="toggleOnByInput()"></i></th>
      <th>S/N</th>
              <th>Proposed name(s)</th>
              <th>Presenter</th>
              <th>Date of Request</th>
              <th>Duration in queue (days)</th>
              <th>Data Entry Officer</th>
              <th>Reassigned by</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td>
      <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger"  id="toggle-trigger" onClick="checkbox();" value="4" name="box">
    </td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
      <td>audu Uthman</td>
      <td> 
       <button class="btn btn-success"> View Details</button> 
    </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
      <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger"  id="toggle-trigger" onClick="checkbox();" value="3" name="box">
    </td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
      <td>audu Uthman</td>
      <td> 
       <button class="btn btn-success"> View Details</button> 
    </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
      <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger"  id="toggle-trigger" onClick="checkbox();" value="1" name="box">
    </td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
      <td>audu Uthman</td>
      <td> 
       <button class="btn btn-success"> View Details</button> 
    </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
      <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger"  id="toggle-trigger"  onClick="checkbox();" value="2" name="box">
    </td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
      <td>audu Uthman</td>
      <td> 
       <button class="btn btn-success"> View Details</button> 
    </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
      <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger"  id="toggle-trigger">
    </td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
      <td>audu Uthman</td>
      <td> 
       <button class="btn btn-success"> View Details</button> 
    </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
      <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger"  id="toggle-trigger">
    </td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
      <td>audu Uthman</td>
      <td> 
       <button class="btn btn-success"> View Details</button> 
    </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
      <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger"  id="toggle-trigger">
    </td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
      <td>audu Uthman</td>
      <td> 
       <button class="btn btn-success"> View Details</button> 
    </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
      <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger"  id="toggle-trigger">
    </td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
      <td>audu Uthman</td>
      <td> 
       <button class="btn btn-success"> View Details</button> 
    </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
      <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger"  id="toggle-trigger">
    </td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
      <td>audu Uthman</td>
      <td> 
       <button class="btn btn-success"> View Details</button> 
    </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
      <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger"  id="toggle-trigger">
    </td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
      <td>audu Uthman</td>
      <td> 
       <button class="btn btn-success"> View Details</button> 
    </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
      <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger"  id="toggle-trigger">
    </td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
      <td>audu Uthman</td>
      <td> 
       <button class="btn btn-success"> View Details</button> 
    </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
      <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger"  id="toggle-trigger">
    </td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
      <td>audu Uthman</td>
      <td> 
       <button class="btn btn-success"> View Details</button> 
    </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
      <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger"  id="toggle-trigger">
    </td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
      <td>audu Uthman</td>
      <td> 
       <button class="btn btn-success"> View Details</button> 
    </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
      <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger"  id="toggle-trigger">
    </td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
      <td>audu Uthman</td>
      <td> 
       <button class="btn btn-success"> View Details</button> 
    </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
      <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger"  id="toggle-trigger">
    </td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
      <td>audu Uthman</td>
      <td> 
       <button class="btn btn-success"> View Details</button> 
    </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
      <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger"  id="toggle-trigger">
    </td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
      <td>audu Uthman</td>
      <td> 
       <button class="btn btn-success"> View Details</button> 
    </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
      <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger"  id="toggle-trigger">
    </td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
      <td>audu Uthman</td>
      <td> 
       <button class="btn btn-success"> View Details</button> 
    </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
      <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger"  id="toggle-trigger">
    </td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
      <td>audu Uthman</td>
      <td> 
       <button class="btn btn-success"> View Details</button> 
    </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
      <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger"  id="toggle-trigger">
    </td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
      <td>audu Uthman</td>
      <td> 
       <button class="btn btn-success"> View Details</button> 
    </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
      <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger"  id="toggle-trigger">
    </td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
      <td>audu Uthman</td>
      <td> 
       <button class="btn btn-success"> View Details</button> 
    </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
      <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger"  id="toggle-trigger">
    </td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
      <td>audu Uthman</td>
      <td> 
       <button class="btn btn-success"> View Details</button> 
    </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
      <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger"  id="toggle-trigger">
    </td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
      <td>audu Uthman</td>
      <td> 
       <button class="btn btn-success"> View Details</button> 
    </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
      <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger"  id="toggle-trigger">
    </td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
      <td>audu Uthman</td>
      <td> 
       <button class="btn btn-success"> View Details</button> 
    </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
      <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger"  id="toggle-trigger">
    </td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
      <td>audu Uthman</td>
      <td> 
       <button class="btn btn-success"> View Details</button> 
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time a checkbox is toggled get the length of the checked checkboxes.

Instead of setting a single click handler for each checkbox you could just set one event handler on the table element and take benefit of event bubbling

```
let table = document.getElementById('godwin');
table.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  if (ev.target.matches('[type="checkbox"]')) {
    console.log("You checked %d checkbox(es)", 
    document.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]:checked').length);
  }
});
```

> [Proof of concept](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vVZKqd)

Comment: the issue is once the checkbox is made a toggle design it doesnt work, im using bootstrap data toggle instead of the default checkbox as you can see data-toggle="toggle".